# DXA 1.2 .Net Keyword List

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.2

I have a Schema in Tridion that has a field where the values are set from a Category as a check box list. I can see that you can use the Tag Model for a a single Keyword field but how do you map a check box list that returns multiple values

When I set the field type to `Tag` I get the first Keyword selected in the list.

```
[SemanticProperty("s:services")]
public Tag Services { get; set; }
```

When I set the field to `List<Tag>` I get nothing.

```
[SemanticProperty("s:services")]
public List<Tag> Services { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have not had much time to look into this, but since the keyword field is a multivalue vield, are you using the correct mapping (adding an s to the fieldname), or have you considdered adding a semantic mapping for that specific field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bart's comment was correct. I had named my schema field incorrectly. Quoting the manual:

> When attempting to populate a property of type List, remove any
>   trailing s's from the property name. For example, the Paragraphs
>   property is mapped to Schema field paragraph.

So I modified my schema to rename the field to `service`, changed the model to remove the trailing s, republished the settings page, republished the page that had the Component on it and it all works.

```
[SemanticProperty("s:service")]
public List<Tag> Services { get; set; }
```

This naming convention for lists has tripped me up many times but my brain decided not to figure this one out late yesterday but kicked in this morning!